# parsing XML String with dom4j

Tags: xml, dom4j

This is the **xml** string. I am trying to get the **item** inside the list 
Item can be 1 or more. I want to get item values like Id, pay... 
But I cannot reach to the items. How can I get access to this values with dom4j?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
 <cm>Detail</cm>
 <Code>1</Code>
 <No>20170928</No>
 <Num>1</Num>
 <Flag>Y</end_Flag>
 <list>
  <items>
   <item>
    <Id>01234567</Id>
    <pay>5555</pay>
    <remarksInfo></remarksInfo>
    <d_Date>2017-09-28 16:26:55</d_Date>
    <amount>1.0</amount>
    <Name>ADAM</Name>
    <e_Date>2017-09-28 16:26:55</e_Date>
    <t_Date>2017-09-28 17:46:39</t_Date>
    <damount>1.0</damount>
    <fee>3.0</fee>
    <e_Name>Smith</e_Name>
    <abstractInfo></abstractInfo>
    <Status>S</Status>
    <Code>0026</Code>
    <l_Desc></l_Desc>
    <note></note>
   </item>
<item>
    <Id>01234567</Id>
    <pay>5555</pay>
    <remarksInfo></remarksInfo>
    <d_Date>2017-09-28 16:26:55</d_Date>
    <amount>1.0</amount>
    <Name>ADAM</Name>
    <e_Date>2017-09-28 16:26:55</e_Date>
    <t_Date>2017-09-28 17:46:39</t_Date>
    <damount>1.0</damount>
    <fee>3.0</fee>
    <e_Name>Smith</e_Name>
    <abstractInfo></abstractInfo>
    <Status>S</Status>
    <Code>0026</Code>
    <l_Desc></l_Desc>
    <note></note>
   </item>
  </items>
 </list>
 <hmac>123</hmac>
</data>
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: What are you trying and how does it fail?

Answer (score 7):

I was struggling with the same problem and discovered the solution in the [DOM4J Documentation](https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

> If you have some XML as a String you can parse it back into a Document again using the
> helper method DocumentHelper.parseText()
>
> String text = " James";
>
> Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);

Answer (score -1):

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
         Document document = reader.read( inputFile );

         Element classElement = document.getRootElement();

         List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/data/list/items" );
         System.out.println("----------------------------");

         for (Node node : nodes) {
        //get ID & Pay under item
           String id = node.selectSingleNode("Id").getText()
           String pay = node.selectSingleNode("Pay").getText()

         }
```

In for loop, extract  &  under .

Comment: But xml is String not file

Comment: There are multiple variants of read() method. Check https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.0.1/org/dom4j/io/SAXReader.html#read-java.io.File-

Comment: Specifically, there is a read() method that accepts a Reader, so you can give it a StringReader() that wraps your XML string.